# dispaying slideshow on drupal homepage

Tags: drupal-7

I am building a website with drupal 7 in which I have two user roles i.e. a member and an expert. I want to display slideshow of expert type of users with their image, name and few lines describing them in every instance of slideshow. All 3 fields which I require are stored in mysql database as the users entered these details at the time of signup. I used view_slideshow module but I am unable to configure it my way. Unable to create new content type. 
Can it be possible to display slideshow in the way I want?
I am using "busy" theme if its required.

Comment: You could do this with a block and blocktheme. You just configure the block to only show on the pages you want and to the user type that you want in the block settings, then put the code for the query and display in the blocktheme.

Answer (score 0):

Using the views slideshow module you should be able to create a view where instead of displaying content you display users. On the create view page there is a spot where it says 'show: content ' as a drop down. Change this to users and then when you have the views slideshows module change the display format on the same page to slideshow.